# How to use lucene to search

Tags: lucene

I want to find this word "且试天下" .it is a chinese word.
so the key is "且试天下"

but when i search ,the result contains three document like this.

**且试天下**

**且**共从容

梦之无游**天下**录

actually i only want to get the first result.only the first is the same as the key.the second and the third just contains some word in the key.

Here is my code And i use the lucene 5.5

```
public void doSearch() throws Exception {
        String key = "且试天下";
        Path path = FileSystems.getDefault().getPath("D:/Lucene/StoryExercise", "index");
        Directory directory = new NIOFSDirectory(path);
        IndexReader ir = DirectoryReader.open(directory);
        IndexSearcher is = new IndexSearcher(ir);
        Analyzer analyzer = new SmartChineseAnalyzer();
        Builder builder = new BooleanQuery.Builder();
        QueryParser qp = new ComplexPhraseQueryParser("filename", analyzer);
        Query parse = qp.parse(key);
        builder.add(new BooleanClause(parse, BooleanClause.Occur.MUST));
        BooleanQuery build = builder.build();
        TopDocs td = is.search(build, 100);
        ScoreDoc[] docs = td.scoreDocs;
        Document doc = null;
        int i = 1;
        for (ScoreDoc sd : docs) {
            doc = is.doc(sd.doc);
            System.out.println(doc.get("filename") + "  HAS THE WORD : " + key + i++);
        }
    }
```

Here is the code building the index

```
public void doIndex() throws Exception {
        Path path = FileSystems.getDefault().getPath("D:/Lucene/StoryExercise", "index");
        Directory directory = new NIOFSDirectory(path);
        Analyzer analyzer = new SmartChineseAnalyzer();
        IndexWriterConfig iwc = new IndexWriterConfig(analyzer);
        IndexWriter iw = new IndexWriter(directory, iwc);

        File filedir = new File("D:/Lucene/StoryExercise/data");
        Document doc = null;
        for (File file : filedir.listFiles()) {
            doc = new Document();
            doc.add(new TextField("path", file.getPath(), Field.Store.YES));
            doc.add(new TextField("filename", file.getName(), Field.Store.YES));
            doc.add(new TextField("content", new FileReader(file)));
            iw.addDocument(doc);
        }
        iw.close();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Analyzers are intended to split strings into tokens.  The `SmartChineseAnalyzer` splits "且试天下" into "且", "试", and "天下", much like `StandardAnalyzer` would split "Who Gets the World" into "who", "gets", and "world".

If you want to search as a phrase, your query should be quoted: `qp.parse("\"且试天下\"");`

If you don't want the field to be analyzed, index it as a `StringField` (or use `KeywordAnalyzer`).

Comment: i really appreciate you ,your answer is so detailed..could you recommend me some book or doc to learn the lucene .the official doc don't have detailed knowledge or maybe i can't find it.. ORN. thanks .

Comment: @Vincent - You could take a look at the Getting Started section of [the documentation](https://lucene.apache.org/core/5_5_0/index.html), particularly the [Analysis Overview](https://lucene.apache.org/core/5_5_0/core/org/apache/lucene/analysis/package-summary.html#package_description).  As far as a book, [Lucene in Action](https://www.manning.com/books/lucene-in-action-second-edition) is the typical recommendation, but bear in mind, the code is getting pretty outdated there (written with Lucene 3.0.1, current version is 5.5.0, and the differences will be pretty significant)